# Can nfs4 with kerberos work with strong encryptions?

Tags: encryption, nfs

Is it possible to use strong encryption (anything else than DES) with NFS4 and kerberos? What's required to get it working on natty?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, you can now specify any available encryption type:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto#NFSv4%20with%20Kerberos

> Please note that you can now (with
>   Ubuntu 8.04 and later) use any
>   encryption type you want, there is no
>   more need to extract only des-cbc-crc,
>   as most sites suggest. See
>   [http://mailman.mit.edu/pipermail/kerberos/2008-May/013698.html
>   this mailinglist message].

Comment: According to the linux kernel source http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/sunrpc/auth_gss/gss_krb5_mech.c?v=2.6.37 it should support AES128 and AES256. Any clues why it's not working in natty (which has a 2.6.38 kernel)?